# Salesforce Flow - Identify Latest Task based on Custom Date Field

Tags: workflow, process-builder, visual-workflow, loop

I have an existing Task flow that I am looking to modify.

The current flow as designed takes in the current Task record that is created under an Account, iterates through a loop, then ticks off a checkbox titled Task.Most_Recent__c.

If I wanted to check a collection of **all** existing Task records under an Account including the record currently being created, find the most recent (max) date under a custom field called Task.CompletedDate in this collection of records, then check a box called Task.Most_Recent__c, what elements would I need to add/update on my flow?

[image: Task Flow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would start with an Assignment to assign the current task to an sobject variable, then in your loop, you would need a Decision to determine if that record's date is greater than the sobject variable, and if so, an Assignment to assign that task as the latest. After your loop, you probably need another Assignment to specify the values you want to set, and then the rest of the flow (updating the records) would be the last step.

Comment: are there elements in my current flow that I can use?  Or would I have to build a brand new flow?

Comment: @CDG I envision that you could do this in your existing flow; the assignment goes before the loop, the Decision/Assignment part goes in your loop, then the final Assignment/Fast Update after the loop.